# Dell Inspiron 7560 Laptop - Install SSD

Tags: ssd, dell-inspiron

I am using Dell Inspiron 7000 Core i5 7th Gen - 7560 Laptop, which didn't have SSD by default.

Could you please suggest some ssd models that i can purchase of this laptop.

I found [this](https://www.komplett.no/product/1003360/datautstyr/lagring/harddiskerssd/ssd-m2/crucial-mx500-500gb-m2-ssd#) model. But I am not sure if it is compatible with my machine or not.

Please help

Comment: I am new to superuser. And I am asking this question because I dont know about the ssd that suits my laptop. It is very sad that your are closing the thread.

Comment: I have even asked the same question here as well https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-Inspiron-7000-Corei5-7th-Gen-7560-Laptop-Install-SSD/td-p/7311681

Comment: You can't ask for recommendations, there is a [website for that](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com). If you ask what SSD would fit on your laptop it's ontopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add an m.2 ssd or sata ssd based on the specifications of your computer.

The link you posted did not work for me.

I would suggest a crucial sata ssd mx500

Comment: Are you suggesting this one ??Crucial MX500 500GB M.2 SSD
M.2 2280, SATA 3.0, up to 560/510MB/s read/write

Comment: @WAS is correct.  Page 14 of https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-7560-laptop_specifications_en-us.pdf shows you can install any standard SATA III 2.5" drive, and also install any M.2 SATA III drive. Do not try to install an NVMe PCIe M.2 drive. https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-7560-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf shows how to install them.

Comment: Is it possible for me to install  this one https://www.amazon.com/Crucial-MX500-500GB-2280SS-Internal/dp/B077SQ8J1V/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=Crucial+MX500+500GB+M.2+SSD&qid=1559793798&s=gateway&sr=8-3

Comment: what is the diff b.w M.2 SATA III and  NVMe PCIe M.2? How we differentiate this two.

Comment: @sooraj - I think that ssd is compatible

Comment: I tried the same it was working fine. :) Thank you so much :)